# How to start the camel quartz job using cron expression at service start up

Tags: spring-boot, cron, apache-camel

My route is scheduled to run once a month at 1:00 AM and there will be a problem if my app is down during that time so I wanted to run the job at application startup.

It worked with time period ( job runs if the service is restarted) but not with cron Expression.

I have tried using the following but no luck.

from("quartz2://scheduler?cron=0 45 15 1 1/1 ?&trigger.misfireInstruction=1&recoverableJob=true&&stateful=true")

Can someone please let me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I could not comment. This is not answer but

```
from("file:C:\\dev\\Repository\\ware3?fileName=ff.txt&scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=0/3+*+*+*+*+?")
```

So, change cron with **+**:

Answer (score 0):

Since [Camel 3.13.0](https://camel.apache.org/releases/release-3.13.0/) new feature [camel-quartz: allow missfire execution for cron triggers](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-17133) available:

```
// daily trigger started a day ago
from("quartz://daily?triggerStartDelay=" + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(-1L) + "&cron=0+0+0+*+*+?")
```